# Live-Server not working in Visual Studio Code port 5500

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS code and web developing altogether. I created a website a few hours ago and ran it with live server on VS code, and everything was fine. Now I'm trying to run another website but when I run the live server, the old site pops up. I noticed that port 5500 is part of the URL and there's no file uploaded (meaning no .html) but the old site is on my browser. I've read about changing port 5500 but don't understand those instructions, when I go to the VS code settings, I find the option but can't find how to change the port...

I uninstalled and installed the extension, and nothing.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You're using vscode live server?

Comment: Yes. I kind of solved it. The problem was that my new project wasn't in the correct folder for vscode.

Comment: Why not you're using live-server of npm, it's really amazing!